# Dreamweaver library items - links and images gets "library/"

Tags: dreamweaver

Hello Stackoverflow this is my first post, but you have already helped me alot of times!

However, I have made a Footer as a library item on my site. The problem is that, when I add the library item into my site, every links and images get "library/" before.

**Example:** In the library item the link to my image is "images/about-us.png", but it turn so "library/images/about-us.png" when I drag the library item into my site. This results in that the image can't be find and doesn't show up.

*Any ideas is very helpfull!*

*/Rasmus (DW CS5.5)*

Answer (score 0):

Did you originally have a folder in the root of your site called 'library'? If so, that may have confused Dreamweaver, as by default, they store all library items in a root-level folder called 'Library' (with a capital L). And if that folder doesn't exist, Dreamweaver should try to create it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no my root site folder is shoppahemsida and dreamweaver automatically added a "Library" folder to it.